# Generate date series including next row value

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have a table:

```
 ╔════════════╦════════╦════════════╗
 ║ product_id ║ amount ║ date       ║
 ╠════════════╬════════╬════════════╣
 ║ 1          ║ 100    ║ 2019-01-01 ║
 ║ 2          ║ 150    ║ 2019-01-01 ║
 ║ 1          ║ 200    ║ 2019-01-05 ║
 ║ 2          ║ 180    ║ 2019-01-03 ║
 ║ 2          ║ 150    ║ 2019-01-05 ║
 ╚════════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

**I need to generate rows of products based on the next row value(amount). I need something like this in result:**

```
╔════════════╦════════╦════════════╗
║ product_id ║ amount ║ date       ║
╠════════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ 1          ║ 100    ║ 2019-01-01 ║
║ 1          ║ 100    ║ 2019-01-02 ║
║ 1          ║ 100    ║ 2019-01-03 ║
║ 1          ║ 100    ║ 2019-01-04 ║
║ 1          ║ 200    ║ 2019-01-05 ║
║ 2          ║ 150    ║ 2019-01-01 ║
║ 2          ║ 150    ║ 2019-01-02 ║
║ 2          ║ 180    ║ 2019-01-03 ║
║ 2          ║ 180    ║ 2019-01-04 ║
║ 2          ║ 150    ║ 2019-01-05 ║
╚════════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` in an aggregate subquery to generate the "missing" dates.

Then, we need to bring the preceeding non-null amount on new rows - this would have been straight-forward if Postgres supported the `ignore nulls` option to `lag()` - but it doesn't. One way to work around this is to use a window count to define the groups, and then `first`value()`:

```
select
    product_id, 
    dt,
    first_value(amount) over(partition by product_id, grp order by dt) amount
from (
    select 
        x.*, 
        t.amount,
        count(*) filter(where t.amount is not null) 
            over(partition by x.product_id order by x.dt) grp
    from (
        select product_id, generate_series(min(date), max(date), '1 day'::interval) dt
        from mytable
        group by product_id
    ) x
    left join mytable t on t.product_id = x.product_id and t.date = x.dt
) t
order by product_id, dt
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32199bb76135513a13512d063b6127c4)**:

```
product_id | dt                     | amount
---------: | :--------------------- | -----:
         1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00+00 |    100
         1 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00+00 |    100
         1 | 2019-01-03 00:00:00+00 |    100
         1 | 2019-01-04 00:00:00+00 |    100
         1 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00+00 |    200
         2 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00+00 |    150
         2 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00+00 |    150
         2 | 2019-01-03 00:00:00+00 |    180
         2 | 2019-01-04 00:00:00+00 |    180
         2 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00+00 |    150
```